# Loading Pinterest asynchronously not working

Tags: jquery, pinterest

I have been using [Blackfish Web's][1] script for asynchronously loading a bunch of social media plugins such as Facebook and Twitter. I have tried including Pinterest but it doesn't seem to want to work, instead it goes to: http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/ and I don't know how to fix it.

```
function loadSocial() {
   if (typeof (pinterest) != 'undefined') {
      pinterest.widgets.load();
   } else {
      $.getScript('http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js');
   }
}

window.onload = function() {
   loadSocial();
};

<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a>
```